# Error when dividing a field with a number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

Using arcpy CalculateField_management i want to divide a field with a spacific number:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(EZG_shp, "IDX_AT_PK", "(!EURO_SUM!/!Anz_Pers!)/1668,4","PYTHON")
```

This works in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1 fine, but the result in arcpy is an error (No NULL-Values a allowed)...

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any nulls in fields EURO_SUM or Anz_Pers?

Comment: no null values - all fields are double and have values. the strange thing is, that it works with the field calculator in arcGIS desktop.

Comment: does it also work with the calculate field tools in ArcGIS desktop ?

Comment: radouxju meant using the Calculate Field GP tool (Data Management toolbox)

Comment: Does this work?  `arcpy.CalculateField_management(EZG_shp, "IDX_AT_PK", "(!EURO_SUM! or 0/!Anz_Pers! or 0)/1668.4","PYTHON")`

Comment: Any 0's? - divide by zero has long been an error. Be careful about putting a 0 after the slash. Apart from that it looks fine. As you stated they are double fields so it's unlikely that pythonic 'duck typing' has caused problems - if one were a text field then this could be the case. If it causes problems you can try cursoring through in python, calculating as you go, and find the broken values.

Comment: radouxju: no, i got the same error with GP tool.

Comment: Jason: the error still exists with your code sampe.  Is there a way to upload my shape here in stackexchange?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of background server throw an exception while executing.
Please "disable" your background processing to execute your code in the foreground processing environment.

Go to: `Geoprocessing` > `Geoprocessing Options` on the Standard toolbar. Under `Background Processing`, uncheck the `Enable` checkbox.

Your code is fine, I think comma is typo error in expression `1668,4` replace it with decimal `1668.4`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but neither disabling the background processing nor replacing the comma ended in an accurate solution. It's quite frustrating - any other suggestions?